# How to add a conditional billing field based in Country in "Commerce Kickstart"?

Tags: commerce

I added a new billing **mandatory** field called "NIN Number" at `admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields`

But I only need to show this new field only if the selected country is **United Kingdom**

How can I do this?

Will the https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module be usefull to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use conditional fields because of the internal structure of the addressfield module, you need to use some custom code here, using the #states property and checking against the value of the country. 
Using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), you can edit that form, here's an example of #states coming from the [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module:

```
  $form['high_school'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('High School Information'),
    // This #states rule says that the "high school" fieldset should only
    // be shown if the "student_type" form element is set to "High School".
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'high_school'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module for that.

After installing the module, you need to create field dependency (e.g. by going to: Administration » Store » Customer profiles » Profile types » Billing information » Manage dependencies).

So dependent field is your NIN/VAT field, dependee is your Country/address field.

For standard fields (e.g. [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries)) it should work straightforward.

If you're using Country as part of [Address Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield), then you can set input mode to Regular expression with value (e.g. `GB`, two `GB|US` and so on) and custom jQuery selector for dependee (e.g. `select.country`).

---

Eventually in form alter or for custom forms (as already suggested), something like:

```
// Show NIN field if user selected "United Kingdom" as a Country.
$form['account']['login']['field_profile_nin']['field_profile_nin'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="account[login][field_profile_country][field_profile_country][und]"]' => array('value' => 'GB'),
  ),
);
```